# Doubt: Prove that the circumcircles of $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ADE$ are tangent with $\sqrt {BC}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, inversive-geometry

[image]

So, I recently started inversion and I have doubt in this solution . It's from "A beautiful Journey through Olympiad geometry " by Stefan Lozanovski. This Problem uses $\sqrt{BC}$

Here , I couldn't understand this line

> Furthermore, the circles $\omega _1$
> and $\omega_2$ are tangent to $(ABC)$ and to the parallel lines $\ell'$ and $BC$, so they are
> symmetric with respect to the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.Thus, $D'$ and $E'$
> are symmetric with respect to the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ as well.

I understood that it's enough to show that $D'E'\parallel BC $ , and I also observed that $\omega _1$
and $\omega_2$ are congruent . But the above lines aren't clear , can someone explain it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You may use coordinate geometry too... It is lengthy though, but completely mechanical... You need not think much...just do whatever is asked

Comment: In standard English, the word "doubt" is far from synonymous with "question".

Comment: @SunainaPati, do you have soft copy of this book? I wasn't able to find it online.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed, this is a key feature of Indian English.

Comment: @cosmo5   yes , I do have and recently the volume 1.4 released (just 6 days back ) https://www.olympiadgeometry.com/the-book.html just click on download , it's free

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I think it's saying that $\omega_1^{'}$ and $\omega_2^{'}$ are congruent circles between two parallel lines. So they are symmetric wrt any chord parallel to these two lines. To see this, just draw perpendicular bisector of BC. So $BT'_{2}=CT'_{1}$ where  $T'_{i}$ is tangency point of $\omega_i^{'}$ wrt BC.

Comment: Perpendicular bisector of BC passes through center of (ABC).

Comment: Oh..yeah got it ..thanks @cosmo5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically Thales' theorem. Let $O_1,O_2,O$ be centers of $\{\omega_1', \omega_2',\odot(ABC)\}$. Thus, $O_1-D'-O$ and $O_2-E'-O$ are collinear. Trivially, $\omega_1'$ and $\omega_2'$ have same radius say $r$. Thus, $OO_1=OO_2=r+R$ where $R$ is radius of $\odot(ABC)$. Further, $OD'=OE'=R\overset{\text{Thales'}}{\implies} D'E'\|O_1O_2$ but $O_1O_2\| BC\implies D'E'\| BC$ so done.